# How to fix Undefined offset: 2?

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to push an item of array to another array.

```
$index = 0;
        foreach($d as $single){

            if(!in_array($single,$Fresh_Record['date'])){
                if(count($Fresh_Record['date']) >= $index){
                    $map_array['date'] = $Fresh_Record['date'][$index];
                    $map_array['counter'] = 0;
                }
            }

            $index++;
        }
```

where

```
$d =  [
  0 => "2019-01-17"
  1 => "2019-01-16"
  2 => "2019-01-15"
  3 => "2019-01-14"
  4 => "2019-01-13"
  5 => "2019-01-12"
  6 => "2019-01-11"
]
```

And

```
$Fresh_Record =  [
    "date" => array:2 [
        0 => "2019-01-10"
        1 => "2019-01-14"
    ]
    "counter" => array:2 [
        0 => 1000.0
        1 => 500.0
    ]
]
```

But it's return error `Undefined offset: 2`.

Actaully I am trying to store dates into `$map_array['date']` from `$d` which are not it `$Fresh_Record['date']`.

Also same thing with the `counter`, as you can see in the array. So date not available in `$Fresh_Record['date']` then I want to add the date from `$d` to 
`$map_array['date']` and also counter `0`.

After @SPlatten  Comment

```
$index = 0;
        foreach($d as $single){

            if(!in_array($single,$Fresh_Record['date'])){

                if(isset($Fresh_Record['date'][$index]))
                    $map_array['date'] = $Fresh_Record['date'][$index];
                } 
            }

            $index++;
        }
```

Comment: Just to check - what would you expect `$map_array` to look like in the end.

Comment: You should test for the presence of the item in the array with isset($Fresh_Record['date'][$index])  before attempting to reference it.

Comment: Why not just add all the dates and array_unique it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @SPlatten I did your suggested solution but it is returning this error `syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), `

Comment: @ScriptLover, can you show your modified code?

Comment: @SPlatten I have edited check the question

Comment: @ScriptLover, your original code is wrong, you test for count being larger than the array then index into it anyway.

Comment: @SPlatten can you guide me how can I fix it

Comment: Change if(isset($Fresh_Record['date'][$index])) to if(!isset($Fresh_Record['date'][$index])), then in your code change $map_array['date'] = $Fresh_Record['date'][$index]; to $Fresh_Record['date'][$index] = $single;

Answer (score -1):

There's a problem with your `$Fresh_Record` array. The array is not correctly formed. It should look like this

```
$Fresh_Record =  [
    "date" => [
        0 => "2019-01-10"
        1 => "2019-01-14"
    ]
    "counter" => [
        0 => 1000.0
        1 => 500.0
    ]
]
```

Comment: try it out and see the output

Comment: That is what the link is I posted above, did you try clicking on it?